# custom suggestion in search widget from a network resource

Tags: android, json, networking, android-contentprovider

I have to create custom suggestions for a search widget in android. These suggestion are updated while user is entering text in search box. Suggestion are retrieved from network resource. Data returned from network resource is in json format. Problem is creation of content provider which retrieves data from network resource. Since accessing internet requires different thread. How would we define content provider's query method to retrieve data from internet.

Answer (score 1):

use AsyncQueryHandler

A helper class to help make handling asynchronous ContentResolver queries easier.

Comment: can u just give a small example to access internet resource from content provider using AsyncQueryHandler. I doesn't need to work. It would be a great help

Comment: create a class AQH extends AsyncQueryHandler and override onQueryComplete, to use it call startQuery and the request will be executed in the background Thread and when finished onQueryComplete will be called

Comment: so in query function of Content provider we have to call AsyncQueryHandler. I just want to know how ContentProvider uses AsyncQueryHandler to handle query not how to implement AsyncQueryHandler.

Comment: Also how to link ContentProvider to searchView? Is it through SearchableInfo. where do we call ContentProvider Query method or is it called automatically. How to specify arguments of query method if it is automatically called?

Comment: Ok if you use a quick box search you can forget about AQH and do your network stuff directly in ContentProviders query() method as it is called always in separate non ui thread, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html how to setup thingd

Answer (score -1):

Just follow the [tutorial in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html).  It goes through definition and creation of a custom content provider, both for search and content access.

Comment: I have already gone through that. My problem is different. It is accessing internet resource, which returns in json format. Content provider which I would make will be in main thread and accessing internet resource requires different thread.

Comment: Btw why do you need a ContentProvider? is it because you need it for a Quick Search Bix?